# How to remove a once-off value for a field from django models

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to know how can I remove this default value I set.

While migrating, I was prompted to give a once off value for a field which could not be null, I assigned the value of 0 to it.
[image: Here is where I assigned the value 0]

Now I get this error:
[image]

I have commented out that specific field, and what confuses me as well is that it's an image field not an autofield, though I do have a faint memory of having an autofield. I double check the other app's models for this field, but I haven't found another. I also deleted the tables from the database and migration files multiple times since I got this error, but I'm still sitting with this problem.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it happens when we face some error and we do migrate so that error cause probelm and pops again and again.

so if you had undo error line just write following in terminal to get out of error loop

"python manage.py migrate --fake"

after this your error problem will be solved and you can run your code again.